# i sent bitcoin from my coinbase account to my bittrex account but i used the Bitcoin cash address on accident

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, blockchain.info, transaction-verification, cross-chain-recovery

I have sent bitcoin from my coinbase account to my bittrex account but i have used my bitcoin cash address from bittrex on accident, Where did my money go and is there a way i could access it thru chain block and if so how can i do that? Please help me out with this i'm fairly new to this and don't know what to do, How can i get my money back?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try contacting Coinbase and/or Bittrex, however when you open your bitcoin cash wallet on Bittrex it clearly says, "Depositing tokens to this address other than BCH may result in your funds being lost", so there's no guarantee.